# Analytical solution to non linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am looking for an analytical solution for this PDE:
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left ( \frac{1}{h} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \right )
$$
with the boundary condition of :
$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}|_{x=0}=0 
$

I am wondering if this PDE has appeared in any problem in physics or math, if so what's the solution ?

Comment: You need 2 boundary conditions and 1 initial condition

Comment: yes, I'm more focused on the PDE itself, whether has it been studied before or not.

Comment: Actually, Wolfram Alpha finds some general solutions to your equation (not THE general solution,  since you still need to specify all the conditions, otherwise for PDE it's quite tricky). Use the input D[1/h[x,t] D[h[x,t],x],x] = D[h[x,t],t]

Comment: thanks a bunch! The answer Wolfram gives doesn't agree with the BC. I also find some article in which they used self similar solution, but I think as you said the initial solution is important in this case also.

Comment: Maybe try substitution $h(x,t) = u(t) e^{s(x,t)}$, and consider some special cases

Comment: This is a special case of a class of equations usually referred to as "fast diffusion equation". What is your spatial domain?

Comment: the spatial domain is one direction, $x=0$ is the symmetrical boundary condition, and for the other end, an arbitrary point, a zero flux boundary condition ($t$ represent time).